# Spring - display image on jsp file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

my model store image described with file name (as String) and data (as byte array). I use Hibernate and here's my model:

```
@Entity
public class Image {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] data;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "IMAGE_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Lob
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

But I want to display my stored image, on web site like:

```
<img src="${image.data}" alt="car_image"/>
```

How could I do that?

Should I write controller that serve requests for images?

Any code examples?

---

UPDATE

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/configs/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You cannot do it like this. Your image must be exposed somehow via normal URL. In Spring MVC create a controller that returns an image (raw data) under particular URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/imageController/{imageId}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] helloWorld(@PathVariable long imageId)  {
  Image image = //obtain Image instance by id somehow from DAO/Hibernate
  return image.getData();
}
```

Now useit in your JSP page. This is how HTTP/HTML work:

```
<img src="/yourApp/imageController/42.png" alt="car_image"/>
```

In Spring MVC before 3.1 you might need to do a little bit more coding on controller side. But the principle is the same.

Comment: I've tryied this solution, but I'm getting 404 error. Is it because of my view configuration, that use Tiles? I've put configurations in update

Comment: So finally, 404 error was caused by servlet mapping, that served requests for regex *.htm. Your solution works! Thanks! Dzięki:D

Comment: A "Spring MVC + Hibernate + Maven" fully working example: https://sites.google.com/site/adrienitnotes/java/web-apps---spring-mvc-hibernate/spring-form-image-upload-display-from-database-hibernate-simple-mapping

Comment: when I try this, I get all sorts of messed up characters, instead of an image

Comment: calling `getData()` on `BufferedImage` or similar did not work for me. [This mykong article worked best for me to get byte[] from an image](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-byte-in-java/). Key is to 1. get `BufferedImage`, and 2. get `ByteArrayOutputStream` then use `ImageIO.write(buffImage, "jpg", baos)` to load ByteArrayOutputStream then call `.toByteArray()`

Answer (score 18):

```
File file = new File("home/user/test.jpg");
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int b;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while((b=fis.read(buffer))!=-1){
   bos.write(buffer,0,b);
}
byte[] fileBytes=bos.toByteArray();
fis.close();
bos.close();


byte[] encoded=Base64.encodeBase64(fileBytes);
String encodedString = new String(encoded);

ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
map.put("image", encodedString);
```

Now use it in your JSP page following as

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}" alt="..." width="200" height="200">`
```

Comment: The method encodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64

Comment: ^ encode64(byte[]) is under this package:
`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`

Answer (score 6):

You may need to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10510416/186896). I have a similar problem like you and the solution is to convert the byte array to string and set in the img tag like below,

```
 <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<c:out value='${bean.imageByteArrayString}'/>" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking fo the right answer for a couple of days , so I will write the good one for me:

My image is already saved in database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {

 @Lob
 @Column(name="IMG")
 private byte[] img;

// setters getters etc
}
```

Now in my class for example ShowPicture I have to read it:

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encode(product.getImg());
//setters and getters encodedImage
```

Then my jsp page:

```
<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<s:property value='encodedImage'/>' alt="my image" />
```

Simple as that ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late, but here I leave something that served me and maybe someone can help.

I'm also using Spring MVC and Hibernate

In the **model (entity class)** create a variable of type String to do the conversion of type byte to String with Base64.

I did this for a table of countries that I have with its respective flag, and what I wanted was to list in a table in the view all the countries and to the side its flag.

**Model (Entity)**

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
private String name;
private byte[] flag;
private String base64; //Variable to store the conversion of a data byte type to String

@Transient //Annotation so it does not persist in the database
public String getBase64() {
    //Convert the data type byte to String, store it in the variable and return it
    return this.base64 = Base64.encode(this.flag); 
}

public void setBase64(String base64) {
    this.base64 = base64;
}

public Country() {
}

public Country(int id, String name, byte[] flag, String base64) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.flag = this.flag
    this.base64 = this.base64;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "flag")
public byte[] getFlag() {
    return this.flag;
}

public void setFlag(byte[] flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}

}
```

**Repository - Implements is an interface - AbstractDao is an class Abstract**
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import application.model.Country;
    import application.repository.dao.AbstractDao;
    import application.repository.dao.CountryDao;
    import org.hibernate.Criteria;

```
@Repository("countryDao")
public class CountryDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Country> implements CountryDao {

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Country> listCountries() {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria(); //Country.class
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    List<Country> listCountries = criteria.list();
    return listCountries;
}

}
```

**Service - implements is an interface**

```
import application.model.Country;
import application.repository.dao.CountryDao;
import application.service.dao.CountryService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("countryService")
public class CountryServiceImpl implements CountryService {

@Autowired
private CountryDao countryDao;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Country> listCountries() {
    return countryDao.listCountries();
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
import application.model.Country;
import application.service.dao.CountryService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/countries")
public class CountryController {

@Autowired
private CountryService countryService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ListCountries(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listcont", countryService.listCountry());
    return "countries/countries"; //view
}

}
```

**View - countries/countries.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>List Countries</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Flag</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${listcont}" var="country">
         <tr>
          <td>${country.name}</td>
          <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,${country.base64}" /></
         </tr>
        </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
    </table> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] img = yourImgEntity.getData();
response.setContentType("image/*"); 
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");
//spring-core's FileCopyUtils
FileCopyUtils.copy(img, response.getOutputStream());

// or just use codes below instead of FileCopyUtils
//response.getOutputStream().write(img);
//response.getOutputStream().flush();
//response.getOutputStream().close();
```